# HTML 5 video from Google Cloud won't play on Apple Devices

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video, google-cloud-platform

I am currently trying to embed a video onto my website using the HTML5 video tag. The video is currently hosted on Google Cloud Storage.

On my website (http://timothycdavis.co.uk/sample-page/) I cam currently embedding 2 videos with identical code. Both videos are stored on Google Cloud Storage, one video (the one that won't play) by me and another from this tutorial https://weasel.firmfriends.us/HTMLVideoFromCloud/.

For some reason the video that isn't mine plays fine on all devices including apple devices, but my video doesn't play on apple devices.

My video currently has public access enabled. Not sure why it won't play.

My Code is:

```
<div class="hero">
    <video class="afterglow" id="welcome-video" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay controls="true" controlsList="nodownload" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen poster="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0063/4798/0911/files/The_Experience_Placeholder.jpg?13027813379739663262">

        <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/hubert-raymond-webpage/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    </video> 

</div>

<div class="hero">

    <video class="afterglow" id="welcome-video" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay controls="true" controlsList="nodownload" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen poster="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0063/4798/0911/files/The_Experience_Placeholder.jpg?13027813379739663262">

        <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/stewart-golf/follow-mode-cut-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    </video>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lots of troubles come down to valid markup - your example uses same "id" `id="welcome-video"` attribute which is invalid.

Comment: @PeterPajchl Thanks for the response. I've removed the id now, but that hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: my guess is there's going to be an encoding issue (possibly with the audio component) ... if you grab a copy of ffprobe (part of the ffmpeg suite) you can analyse the Sintel and your video and check for differences, and re-encode your to match (or just reencode to make sure the libx264 video and aac audio parameters match the recommended specs)